# Why is it wrong when I want merging two large tiff images with C#?

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, imagemagick

I want to Combine two Large Tiff .I have tried many ways.But I get an error every time.
for example: 
I used the ImageMagic and System.Drowing.Graphics and ImageProcessor and etc .

OneDriveFiles : https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlD9jC3hP9FTcEB2J2rKgp8Lw_E?e=JFVewK

Four files have been shared.

Original Files Name : _1.tif and _11.tif

Created With Magick.NET-Q16-x64 V7.14.3 : dotnet.tif

Created With ImageMagick Q16 v 7.0.8 : magickcmd.tif

System Information :
OP: win 10 x64
Ram:64Gig
Cpu:I7
GPU: 8Gig
FreeSpace:400Gig

Tif Format :

PixelFormat: Format1bppIndexed

size: 2Gig

Mode : bitmap

Compression : lzw

pixel order : interleaved

byte order : lsb

width : 95752px

height : 295464px

horizontal resolution :800dpi

vertical resolution : 2400dpi

bit depth : 1

resolution unit :2

Thanks for the help...

```
/// Use ImageMagick
                using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
                {

                    MagickNET.SetTempDirectory(@"d:\");

                    images.Add(new MagickImage(txtAddress2.Text, new MagickReadSettings { Endian = Endian.LSB }));
                    images.Add(new MagickImage(txtAddress1.Text, new MagickReadSettings { Endian = Endian.LSB }));

                    using (IMagickImage image = images.AppendHorizontally())
                    {
                        image.Endian = Endian.LSB;
                        image.Settings.SetDefine("tiff:endian", "lsb");
                        image.Write(@"d:\output" + new Random().Next() + ".tif");
                    }

                }
```

//////Use System.Drowing

```
 public static Bitmap MergeTwoImages(Image firstImage, Image secondImage)
    {


        int outputImageWidth = firstImage.Width > secondImage.Width ? firstImage.Width : secondImage.Width;

        int outputImageHeight = firstImage.Height + secondImage.Height + 1;

        Bitmap outputImage = new Bitmap(outputImageWidth, outputImageHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(outputImage))
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(firstImage, new Rectangle(new Point(), firstImage.Size),
                new Rectangle(new Point(), firstImage.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            graphics.DrawImage(secondImage, new Rectangle(new Point(0, firstImage.Height + 1), secondImage.Size),
                new Rectangle(new Point(), secondImage.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        return outputImage;
    }
```

For this problem I suggest ...

Comment: While you post many facts your post lacks the most important information: How large are the image (not the file but the pixels sizes and pixel depth)  and what errors exactly do you get..?

Comment: width : 95752px

height : 295464px

horizontal resolution :800dpi

vertical resolution : 2400dpi

bit depth : 1

resolution unit :2

Comment: The files in your onedrive zip are smaller than that: width 15748, height 188992. There are quite a few unknown TIFF tags. Are these non-standard images? Where are they from?

Comment: It was For Test. Original files are larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at your output images and they both seem fine. If you can't view them, it's probably because they are too large for whatever program you are using. They displayed for me in [nip2](https://github.com/libvips/nip2), the [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) GUI, though they took a couple of minutes to open.

Your images are huge: 15,000 pixels across and 180,000 down. They are stored in TIFF files as 1 bit per pixel, but ImageMagick6 will unpack them to five channels and 16 bits per channel for processing, so that's 25GB each. ImageMagick7 will use 32 bits per channel, so 50GB for each image. This is getting close to the limits of your computer -- it's probably rather slow.

[libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) can do operations like this without needing to load whole images into memory: it streams images from input to output in a series of small regions. It will run a stream for each core on your computer, so it's quick too.

It has a good C# binding: [net-vips](https://kleisauke.github.io/net-vips/). I don't actually have it installed on this laptop, so I tried in Python.

```
import sys
import pyvips

left = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[2], access='sequential')
right = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1], access='sequential')
join = left.join(right, 'horizontal', expand=True)
join.tiffsave(sys.argv[3], predictor='none', compression='lzw', squash=True)
```

The bindings are very similar -- you should be able to translate into C# easily.

On this two-core 2015 latop I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e python3 join.py _1.tif _11.tif vips.tif
65832:26.55
```

So it runs in 26s and needs 65MB of memory.

Have you tried deflate compression? It's slower than LZW, but gives better results. Change the save line to be:

```
join.tiffsave(sys.argv[3], compression='deflate', squash=True)
```

Runtime rises to 57s, but the output file is 25% smaller.

libvips has a CLI as well, you could also just enter:

```
vips join _1.tif _11.tif vips.tif[compression=deflate,squash] horizontal --expand
```

Comment: thanks a lot . It works perfectly well and without problems. How can I compress Lzw?

Comment: Hi, the first example in the answer does LZW.

Comment: Oh, you mean at the CLI? Try `vips.tif[predictor=none,compression=lzw,squash]`